# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found

Tags: php, soap

Here is my code

```
  $client = new SOAPClient ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl');
    var_dump($client->cacheTorrent());
```

i got this after `var_dump` of `$client`

```
object(SoapClient)#1 (2) { ["_soap_version"]=> int(1) ["sdl"]=> resource(1) of type (Unknown) }
```

however I am getting this message when i try to find var_dump($client->cacheTorrent());
Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found

but this makes no sense to me because i downloaded the wdsl file and it plainly says that the operation cacheTorrent exists!!

here

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<definitions name='Cache'
  targetNamespace='urn:Torcache'
  xmlns:tns='urn:Torcache'
  xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'
  xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
  xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
  xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
  xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

<message name='cacheTorrentRequest'>
  <part name='torrent' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>

<message name='cacheTorrentResponse'>
  <part name='Result' type='xsd:string'/>
</message>

<portType name='CachePortType'>
  <operation name='cacheTorrent'>
    <input message='tns:cacheTorrentRequest'/>
    <output message='tns:cacheTorrentResponse'/>
  </operation>
</portType>

<binding name='CacheBinding' type='tns:CachePortType'>
  <soap:binding style='rpc'
    transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>

  <operation name='cacheTorrent'>
    <soap:operation soapAction='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes#cacheTorrent'/>
    <input>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </input>
    <output>
      <soap:body use='encoded' namespace='urn:xmethods-delayed-quotes'
        encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'/>
    </output>
  </operation>
</binding>

<service name='CacheService'>
  <port name='CachePort' binding='CacheBinding'>
    <soap:address location='http://torcache.net/api/soap/'/>
  </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

any ideas of why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your client code .... I you run

```
$client = new SOAPClient ( 'http://torcache.net/torcache.wsdl');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

You would get

```
array
  0 => string 'string cacheTorrent(string $torrent)' (length=36)
```

Apparently `cacheTorrent` is expecting a URL which needs to be a valid torrent .. am sure the error was generated on the soap server while trying too validate or access that url

Comment: hello baba thanks for your helpful answer, however i still get this error even after i use an valid url for the opeartion

Comment: my error is this  Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in /home/public_html/manualtorcache.php:8 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://torcache...', 'urn:xmethods-de...', 1, 0) #1 /home/public_html//manualtorcache.php(8): SoapClient->__call('cacheTorrent', Array) #2 /home/public_html/manualtorcache.php(8): SoapClient->cacheTorrent('ZDg6YW5ub3VuY2U...') #3 {main} thrown in

Comment: I am getting a similar issue with SOAP. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Any solution for this error Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Not Found in xxxx?